# MemoryStream doesn't fill attachment

Tags: c#, email, memorystream

I am developing a method for C# where to send as an attachment a byte[].
The method below sends fine the email, but the attachment is always empty.

```
 public bool envio(MailMessage mail, SmtpClient cliente, byte[] origen)
        {
            bool res = true;
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms;
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer;

            ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);

            try
            {    
                writer.Write(origen);
                writer.Flush();                

                System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
                attach.Name = "Mensaje";
                mail.Attachments.Add(attach);

                cliente.Send(mail);

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                res = false;
            }

            finally

            {
                writer.Close();
                writer.Dispose();                
                ms.Close();
                ms.Dispose();
            }
            return res;

        }
```

I am pretty sure it should be something obvious for an expert developer. but I can't find out the solution.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you finish writing to the stream, it's position is at the end of the data. So when someone tries to read from the stream, there's nothing left to read. The solution is simple:

```
writer.Write(origen);
writer.Flush();
ms.Position = 0;
```

Also, since you're dealing with plain text here, be careful about encoding. Use explicit encodings where possible to minimize encoding issues :)

Comment: Thx, you are in the right way. When i send an string like " hello..." it's properly sent, but when i try to send the  byte[] origen it only sends the first 13 bytes... ¿any idea on how to solve this? thx.

Comment: it seems that any time i try to send a byte[] it only sends the first 13 bytes... i have tried with diferent byte[]

Comment: @Dinalan I have no idea what's in that byte array of yours. Since you're not specifying an encoding in your `StreamWriter`, it uses the default of UTF-8. I expect the data in your byte array is *not* in UTF-8, so you get confusion :)

Comment: @Dinalan Actually, going through the documentation, `StreamWriter` doesn't even *have* an overload that takes a byte array. So it's probably using the `object` overload, which probably means you're always writing something like `System.Byte[]` - oh, look, that's exactly 13 bytes in UTF-8! :D Why are you trying to use `StreamWriter` to write a byte array in the first place?

Comment: thx for your time. the byte[] is the result from a encription of a instance that was previously serialized. i have tried also with  a byte[] like this: { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 34, 43, 4, 4, 5, 43, 2, 34, 23, 4, 12,3,2,12,3,1,2,32,1,54,63,12};

Comment: thx, that could be, i will try to send the information in other way, i will keep youupdated

Comment: @Dinalan Well, that definitely doesn't look like UTF-8 plain-text to me :) You can't just pretend a byte sequence is a string and think you can get away with it - just change the content type to binary, and write the data directly to the memory stream.

Comment: Thank you show much!, now it works with binary writer.